# how to read more than 256 bytes over a socket in C

Tags: c, tcp, client

I am facing the problem that my server is sending a string which is of size 600 bytes. Now for reading from the server my client uses the statement

```
   n=read(sockfd,rbuffer,255);
```

where rbuffer is my buffer.

If i try to increase the size mentioned in the read statement (255) i'm getting a segmentation fault.

Now that I know that the client is receiving only the partial information sent by the server.How can I modify or change the way I read the information so that I can read all of the bytes?

PS: the size of the string is so big since I am trying to send an XML string across.

Comment: It honestly never occurred to you to read the man page for read()?

Answer (score 3):

You need to also increase the size of `rbuffer`. One way to do that could be:

```
unsigned char rbuffer[4096];
n = read(socksfd, rbuffer, sizeof(rbuffer));
```

That way if you decide to change the size you only have to do it in one place.

Comment: and you need to rename unsigned char buffer to unsigned char rbuffer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well, when you look at the [read()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) system call documentation, it says that the last argument is the size of your buffer.

In your case, you'll want to make sure that `rbuffer`is large enough!

I guess you have somewhere:

```
unsigned char rbuffer[255];
n = read( sockfd, rbuffer, 255);
```

You'll want to do that:

```
unsigned char rbuffer[1024];
n = read( sockfd, rbuffer, 1024);
```

To be sure not to put an invalid value as the size, use `sizeof( rbuffer )` **if it is allocated on the stack** (like above).

If it is dynamically allocated, you'll have to use the size you used when allocating the buffer:

```
int bufsize = 1024;
char *buffer = malloc(bufsize);
n = read( sockfd, buffer, bufsize);
```

Comment: Uh.. `malloc(sizeof(char), bufsize)` ? malloc takes only one parameter and the size of `char` is by definition 1.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It's been too long since I last approached malloc... :-)

Comment: It's better to use the sizeof operator instead of harcoded integer constants.